# Python binance fetchMyTrades gives only 3 month of personal trades, so how do one iterates through results?

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

I am trying to get my trades earlier than 3 months
I do it like this:

```
#I use ccxt library 
result = ccxt_binance.fetchMyTrades('BTC/USDT', since = 1588669559517)
```

But still get the trades only for 3 months and can't get trads before 2020-05-05
[image]
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the original issue on GitHub here:

- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/7439

An example in Python is available here:

- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/py/binance-fetch-all-my-trades-paginate-by-id.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ccxt


exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    'secret': 'YOUR_SECRET',
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    # 'options': {
    #     'defaultType': 'spot', // spot, future, margin
    # },
})


exchange.load_markets ()

# exchange.verbose = True  # uncomment for debugging

symbol = 'ETH/BTC'
from_id = '0'
params = { 'fromId': from_id }
previous_from_id = from_id

all_trades = []

while True:

    print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Fetching with params', params)
    trades = exchange.fetch_my_trades(symbol, None, None, params)
    print('Fetched', len(trades), 'trades')
    if len(trades):
        # for i in range(0, len(trades)):
        #     trade = trades[i]
        #     print (i, trade['id'], trade['datetime'], trade['amount'])
        last_trade = trades[len(trades) - 1]
        from_id = last_trade['id']
        params['fromId'] = from_id
        if from_id == previous_from_id:
            break
        else:
            all_trades = all_trades + trades
    else:
        break

print('Fetched', len(all_trades), 'trades')
for i in range(0, len(all_trades)):
    trade = all_trades[i]
    print (i, trade['id'], trade['datetime'], trade['amount'])
```